# How many numbers can I make with subseries of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$, what real numbers in $\left[ \frac{1}{2},1 \right]$ can I generate with subseries of this series?

Obviously we have every power of $\frac{1}{2^n}$ (by taking single terms), as well as 1 itself, which is the value of the original series.  But can I get to any real number I want with the appropriate terms?  Informally I would say yes, since we can approach with arbitrary precision by choosing the terms that are as small as I need.

Are all the reals in the interval $\left[ \frac{1}{2},1 \right]$ reachable?  If not, is there a way to characterize "how many" are reachable?

Comment: Hint: Base $2$.

Comment: Every real number in [0.5,1] is of the form 0.XXX... where X is 0 or 1, and each digit corresponds to a term in this series?

Comment: Let me mention a nice generalization: In [*The subset sum of a null sequence*](http://www.tufts.edu/~znitecki/Subsequence%20Sums.pdf‎), Zbigniew Nitecki associates to each sequence $\vec x$ converging to $0$ the set of numbers that are the sum of a subsequence of $\vec x$, the subsequence may be infinite, finite, or even empty. He characterizes the possible shapes of this set. The example in this question is a bounded closed interval including $0$.

Comment: The possibilities are: An unbounded closed interval which includes zero, a finite union of (nontrivial) compact intervals, a Cantor set, or what he calls a “symmetric Cantorval”, that is, a nonempty compact subset $S$ of the real line such that (1) $S$ is the closure of its interior, and (2) Both endpoints of any nontrivial connected component of $S$ are accumulation points of trivial (i.e., one-point) connected components of $S$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, thanks for the reference but your link is broken, is http://www.tufts.edu/~znitecki/Subsum%20Sets%20(v9).pdf the correct paper?

Comment: Ah, how annoying! Yes, that's the one. See also [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3779).

Comment: Some of the results from the paper linked by Andres Caicedo were mention in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81267/surjective-function-from-a-cantor-set).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the pointer. There are some nice references there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any real number has a decimal expansion you can write any real number in base $2$. If you don't allow positive exponents or a minus sign you get all numbers between $0$ and $1$ (both included).

Comment: $1$ *is* included. The series is a "subseries" of itself, and the sum of the series is $1$.

Comment: @dfeuer: Thanks, corrected

Comment: Thanks!  I take it that this approach can also show that if we change 2 to any other natural number, we cannot find subseries that converge to arbitrary reals in the appropriate interval, because the numerator remains equal to 1 and so not every decimal expansion in the corresponding base can be recreated?

Comment: Oof, of course the interval is [0,1], I feel stupid :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. It only works with $2$ because the coefficients of the binary expansion are either $0$ (=omit term) or $1$ (=include term).

Comment: It does, however, work just fine for real numbers in $(1,2]$. Michalis's error was most likely a result of the fact that it's very common to consider base-$k$ representations that don't end in an infinite string of $0$s or ones that don't end in an infinite string of $k-1$s. That lets you get a *unique* representation of real numbers.